# How can I configure the public and cluster network with the juju ceph charm

Tags: juju, ceph

I deployed ceph via juju and the ceph charm.

My servers have 3 NIC's (eth0 for management, eth1, public storage network, eth2 for cluster network).
When I deploy ceph via juju it installs all the monitors and the ODS (local disks) very nicely and easy. When I look at ceph.conf it only uses eth0 for the communication. Changing the ceph.conf does not help as juju overwrites it again.

Is there a way to be able to configure it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Juju has a very simple networking model, which assumes only a "private" (inside the cloud environment) and "public" (externally accessible) networks.

A more sophisticated networking model with support for user-configurable multiple networks is being developed right now, but until it's ready (most likely for the 14.10 release), you should be able to do it manually, after Juju deploys Ceph.

You can even pull the ceph charm's source, tweak it and deploy it from a local repository. Check out Juju documentation on using charms - https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/charms.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Can't wait to test the new version.